# Custom 404 page

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, errordocument

I'm using html5 Boilerplate that has a `404.html` page but if I navigate to a wrong URL it doesn't display. The browser shows the default 404 page. htaccess file has already this line:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Some help?

Comment: are you sure the `/404.html` file exists? You have leading slash `/` which means it will look in the root directory of the server structure...

Comment: Tried to change the slash with other paths and don't work

Answer (score 0):

Does you have set in your directory directive `AllowOverride All`? This must be somewhere in your server configuration. E.g. the virtual host configuration:

```
<Directory /path/to/htdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All # this All here is important, default is none
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I've added all that code in the htaccess but when I navigate to the page I get `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: I expect that you changed the directory. Just to be sure. Could you add the last 10 lines of your error log?

Comment: Yes, but where can I find the error log? 
I've changed `/path/to/htdocs` with some path but I get always 500. Could you tell me what is the correct path? 404 page, htaccess and index.php are situated in www.domain.com/site/

Comment: The error log is normally in a directory like `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. And you added the lines above in a `*.conf` file?

Comment: I've added the <Directory /path/to/htdocs> in the htaccess. I haven't any .conf files. Added error log in first post. I'm using a web host, not on my Apache

Comment: wait! I've tried to use the same htaccess file in the site root (that is domain.com and not domain.com/site) and it works! :\